# What does $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ imply for bounding of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a way to bound the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k}$$ given that you already know the value of $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$$

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k} \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$$

Comment: Are the $a_k$ nonnegative?

Comment: I think there is no way to determine bound first sum using last sum. (I think $a_k=(-1)^{b_k}/\ln(1+k)$ is appropriate example.)

Comment: Or consider $a_k = \begin{cases} M,&\text{when $k=n$} \\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Comment: GitGud, sorry, I guess I should have specified that the most trivial case is not what Im asking. I was hoping to get a little thought put into this. My bad, once again, for choosing this web site.  A tighter bound than that would be excellent.

julien, the reason I used $a_k$ was to denote an arbitrary sequence of values. Im sorry I need to specify this, too. I thought it was implied by the lack of further information.

MJD Im not entirely sure what youre getting at.  You are creating a sequence of one term?

Comment: If we knew the given sum was absolutely convergent then I believe you could apply Dirichlet's test, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a_k}{k} = \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k}{n!} \le \dfrac{\text{any upper bound on $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$ }}{n!} $ but this bounds the partial sum.

Comment: Cogito, if you so dislike this website, you know no one is forcing you to come here. Also, if you want others to put some thought into your question, you might try putting some thought into its presentation yourself. And try putting some thought into the answers of tetori and MJD.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum: it is not necessarily clear *what* is meant by $a_k$. Often people forget to mention conditions such as $a_k\ge0$, or people inadvertently assume such conditions. Although the question is trivial if $a_k\ge0$, it would avoid confusion to mention that this is not the case. Certainly, I see no reason to be upset by such inadvertent assumptions, and definitely not by such questions for clarification.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook: Dirichlet's test applies even if the series is not absolutely convergent. In fact, I have noticed it being most useful when the series is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: similar, sort of related :  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766/if-sum-n-1-infty-a-n3-converges-does-sum-n-1-infty-fraca?rq=1

Comment: I choose math.se because you guys are more competent with deeper knowledge of math.  I end up going to yahoo answers because they end up being more helpful and cooperative, and dont need every little statement defined explained for them.

Comment: @robjohn thanks for the note, I'll try to be less greedy next time.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook: greedy? I must be missing something.

Comment: @robjohn sorry, I mean to say I have assumed more than is required of the Dirichlet Test.

Answer (score 7):

Using the [Dirichlet Convergence Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), if
$$
\left|\,\sum_{k=1}^na_k\,\right|\le A
$$
for all $n$, and if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0$ and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left|\,b_{k+1}-b_k\,\right|=B
$$
Then
$$
\left|\,\sum_{k=1}^na_kb_k\,\right|\le AB
$$
Thus,
$$
\left|\,\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a_k}{k}\,\right|\le\sup_{n\ge1}\,\left|\,\sum_{k=1}^na_k\,\right|
$$
but I don't see an obvious way to get a better bound.

---

Consider the sequence
$$
a_k=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{\left\lfloor{\Large\frac{k+1}2}\right\rfloor}
$$
Then the series
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k(1-1)\\[6pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$
yet
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a_k}{k}
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k\left(\frac1{2k-1}-\frac1{2k}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac2{2k-1}-\frac2{2k}-\frac1{2k^2}\right)\\
&=2\log(2)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\\[10pt]
&\stackrel.=0.563827327695778
\end{align}
$$
Thus, there can be no constant, $c$, so that
$$
\left|\,\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a_k}{k}\,\right|\le c\,\left|\,\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\,\right|
$$

Comment: How does that prove that there can be no constant $c$ whatsoever?  Its fine if $\sum \frac{a_k}{k} \ge \sum a_k$. Im just looking for a way to bound the relationship. And youre assuming that the relationship HAS to be proportional involving a scalar factor... rather than, say, a scalar addition. Furthermore, dont you contradict yourself? The first half of your argument is proving $\sum \frac{a_k}{k} \le \sum a_k$, but then you go on to give an example of the reverse inequality, thus disproving the first half of your argument.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum: the sum on the right side is $0$; the sum on the left side is positive. There is no constant, $c$, so that $2\log(2)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\le c\cdot0$.

Comment: I made about three or four points. Youre going to focus on one? Youre barely touched on what I said. For example, why must the bound be a scalar constant proportionality? Why cant we add or subtract a scalar value?  Is there NO way to bound? Or simply no way to bound with a scalar factor?  Youve only proven that it can be done with one assumption of the form it ought to take.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum: Using the sequence I give above, the sequence $b_1=d+ca_1$ and $b_k=ca_k$ for $k\gt1$ is a sequence so that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty b_k=d$ and yet $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{b_k}{k} =d+c\left(2\log(2)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\right)$. Adjusting $d$ and $c$, we can get any two values for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty b_k$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{b_k}{k}$.